# Display children category images

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, children

I have worked four hours on this but with no result.
There is a custom taxonomy and I need to display the image of the child category but displays the image of parent category.

My code is:

```
<?php 

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = get_queried_object() -> term_id;
$taxonomyName = "product-categories";
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomyName );

$image_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true );

if ($termchildren != false){
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
       $term2 = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
?>

<div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 d-inline-block">
     <img class="img-fluid imgborder" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, '' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $term2 -> name; ?>">
     <h2><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child, $taxonomyName); ?>"><?php echo $term2 -> name; ?></a></h2>
 </div>
```

I know the problem is in this line, but I don't know what exactly I should do.

```
    $image_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true );
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it, but this should do it.

```
    <?php

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = get_queried_object() -> term_id;
$taxonomyName = "product-categories";
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomyName );



if (! empty ( $term_children ) ){
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
       $image_id = get_term_meta( $child, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true );?>
       <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 d-inline-block">
            <img class="img-fluid imgborder" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, '' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $child->name; ?>">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child, $taxonomyName); ?>"><?php echo $child->name; ?></a></h2>
        </div>
  <?php }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, thought it returned an object. Difficult without being able to var_dump();

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the setting of the `$image_id` value within the `foreach` loop so that the image is retrieved for each child term.

Here's complete code with that change made and a few others:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_children = get_term_children( $queried_object->term_id, $queried_object->taxonomy );

if ( ! empty ( $term_children ) ) :
    foreach ( $term_children as $term_id ) :
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $queried_object->taxonomy );
        $image_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true );
        ?>

        <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 d-inline-block">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'thumbnail', false, array( 'class' => 'img-fluid imgborder' ) ); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term_id ) ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>
        </div>

        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Note some of the other changes I made:

1. I got rid of unnecessary values from the beginning and just used `get_queried_object()` to get the term object for the current term, and used its properties for getting the term children.
2. I checked that `$term_children` wasn't *empty*, instead of false. `get_term_children()` will never return an actual `false` value, so `! empty()` is a more accurate representation of what you're checking for.
3. I set `$image_id` inside the `foreach` loop with the current `$term_id` for the child term.
4. I used `wp_get_attachment_image()` instead of `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` because I find it neater than mixing up PHP in HTML attributes.
5. I used `esc_url()` on `get_term_link()` for the extra layer of safety, and I also removed the taxonomy argument from `get_term_link()` because it's not needed and it keeps the code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

works wonderful... thank you Jacob Peattie and Daniel Fonda :)

```
<?php

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = get_queried_object() -> term_id;
$taxonomyName = "product-categories";
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomyName );

if ($termchildren != false){
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $term2 = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        $image_id = get_term_meta( $child, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true );
?>

<div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 d-inline-block">        
    <img class="img-fluid imgborder" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, '' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $term2 -> name; ?>">
    <h2 class="p-4"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child, $taxonomyName); ?>"><?php echo $term2 -> name; ?></a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `$term_id`, you have to use `$termchildren` id and put it in foreach loop

```
if (! empty ( $term_children ) ){
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
   $image_id = get_term_meta( $child, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true );?>
   <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 d-inline-block">
        <img class="img-fluid imgborder" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, '' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $child->name; ?>">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child, $taxonomyName); ?>"><?php echo $child->name; ?></a></h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why did you vote down this answer? what is wrong?

Comment: `$termchildren` is an *Array* of term IDs for the children of the given term. `get_term_meta()` requires an *Integer* for the ID of the one term that you want to get the metadata for. This code wouldn't do anything.

Comment: I mean he have to use $termchildren ' s id and not parent term's id, that is clear to understand

Comment: It's not at all clear to understand. It's the opposite. `$termchildren` is not the variable name in the asker's code, and is in fact the name of a different variable they're using, which is just confusing. And your answer doesn't account for the fact that the whole line of code is in the wrong place and needs to be moved.

Comment: ok, you are right. I was uncareful